# What does "Maximum memory usage reached" mean in the Cassandra logs?

Tags: cassandra

There's a lot of confusion as to what this message means and whether there's any action to take:

```
... NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Maximum memory usage reached (536870912), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
```

Does this pose a problem and should Cassandra operators be concerned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra uses buffer pools when reading off the disk. Decompressed SSTable chunks are stored in a cache allocated from off-heap memory that operates in much the same way as the OS page cache.

When a node is busy, it is quite normal to expect that the cache can fill up quicker than the space can get freed up. When this happens, Cassandra logs this message at `INFO` level because there is no action to take -- the buffer will get allocated anyway but just not from cache.

The chunk cache size is controlled by `file_cache_size_in_mb` with a default value of 512MB. Although it is possible to increase the cache size, there really is not much effect to the nodes, again since there is no significant impact to the cache filling up unless nodes are overloaded and cannot keep up with reads and repeatedly fill up the chunk cache.

As a general rule, when the cluster is correctly-sized (i.e. sufficient number of nodes) you should rarely see this message if at all.