# What can I do about "maximum memory usage reached (...), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576" in Cassandra?

Tags: memory, cassandra

I got this error:

> maximum memory usage reached (536870912), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576.

I have increased the file cache to 1024, but I still get the error related to memory usage. What can I do get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything about it unless your cluster is showing symptoms of being overloaded.

Just to clarify, it is not an error. In fact it is logged at `INFO` level because it is just an informational message, not an error or a warning.

As you are already aware, Cassandra uses a file cache for memory management similar to the OS page cache. If the file cache is oversubscribed, Cassandra will simply allocate memory from another pool -- just not the file cache.

For details, see my answer in this previous post -- [What does "Maximum memory usage reached" mean in the Cassandra logs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314796/). Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are getting the same INFO in logs. Also, we are facing latency alerts (Condition: More than 2 seconds with 5 minutes span). An increase in file_cache_size_in_mb could help here anyway or the condition seems too tight and we can expand that (e.g. 5 seconds in 5 minutes span). No Complaint about latency issues from the Application side.